# URL of web page in bibliography not output

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, lyx, natbib, urls

First time trying to write my thesis in Lyx which has been great up until this point, and getting rather close to submission time I have noticed that webpage references are not outputting with the URL and date accessed like APA states it should.

I am using natbib with the apalike style as bibliography style. I am trying to cite a web site, but in the bibliography the URL (given in the BibTeX entry) is not printed.

I am using Mendeley to keep my references and it shown that it is exported in the URL field

```
@misc{test,
author = {test},
title = {{test prices}},
url = {http://www.test_url.com/our-financials/prices},
urldate = {2015-09-25},
year = {2015}
}
```

But it will not output the URL or date accessed.

[image: Screenshot of the bibliography document settings]

[image: Screenshot of the bibliography settings from inserted bibliography database]

Answer (score 1):

I came across a work around, In the same bibtex I inserted.

```
note = {Retrieved on <Date> from <url>},
```

Just ensure , or } at the end to close of each bibtex entry